# Skip ingame resource download by already keeping the files on the Android device

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've recently learned that, if you have Steam backup files, you can avoid downloading large downloads from Steam.

Now, many of you know that on Google Play Store, some games (i.e. Asphalt, PUGM, WOT Blitz, etc.) download additional game files after installing. The download size can be massive sometimes. So I would like to know if there is a safe way of preserving those additional resource files so that next time when I reinstall the game, I don't have to wait for long to play it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder you're looking for is called "Android" and is in your internal storage. Android apps put their files in either "data" or "obb" folders inside the Android folder.

So

```
/Android/data/
```

and

```
/Android/obb/
```

Then inside those folders there is a folder for each app. The folder will have the same package name as the application. For instance the package name for Real Racing 3 is com.ea.games.r3_row and can be seen in the url in the app store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.games.r3_row&hl=en

I believe it's possible you might have files for the same app in both folders, but don't quote me one this.

This means that the Real Racing 3 files will be in either

```
/Android/data/com.ea.games.r3_row/
```

and/or

```
/Android/obb/com.ea.games.r3_row/
```

You can [use apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Apps%20package%20name&c=apps&hl=en) to associate a package name with an app.

Also I believe there are backup apps out there that CAN backup those files  for you, but I've never needed this o I haven't looked for any.